# Can you use Google App Engine without using its Datastore?

Tags: python, django, database, google-app-engine, serverless

I am planning to develop a web application with Django. Google App Engine (GAE) seems a good place to start. Scalability is the strong feature for me.

But from research, it seems using GAE's API such as Database API throw more problem than expected.

My question is, Could we use GAE with our own database such as MySQL instead?

Comment: "it seems using GAE's API such as Database API throw more problem than expected." - on what are you basing that? links? refs?

Answer (score 6):

**(2023 update)** The main reason to consider App Engine's [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore) *is* scalability... that's why it was built. It's certainly more scalable than the generic open-source RDBMS you can use. Datastore is a NoSQL database which has capabilities of Google's [Bigtable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) research project (which has become its own product [see below]).

However, if you *must have* SQL, you have options:

- [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql) (std MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLserver)
- [Cloud AlloyDB](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb) (high-performance PostgreSQL), or
- [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner) (super-scalable *global* RDBMS)

Since you have a Django app, here's a [link to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) on hosting Django apps on App Engine using Cloud SQL.

If you move away from Django and/or are able to adapt to NoSQL, you also have options beyond Datastore:

- [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) (next-gen Datastore with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) features)
- [Cloud BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable) (even more scalable than Datastore)

[Here's a 2022 Google Cloud blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/databases-google-cloud-part-2-options-glance/) detailing many of these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use GAE, you must use it as-is. Recently i read many announcements about new features, but it's still a sandbox.

If you prefer to be free to choose your own stack, consider Amazon EC2 (i know it's not well considered in these days ;) or Rackspace.

There are also a few Heroku-like services for Django, but imho they are all too much young.